# Suppress basic auth window in Firefox with predefined credentials

Tags: firefox

I've added a bookmark with the following pre-defined credentials:

```
https://user:pass@mydomain.com
```

I entered them in beforehand so I can access the site faster. Everytime I open it the first time in a browser session, Firefox (42.0) shows up the following window asking whether I really want to login with the credentials.

[image: Ask window]

**Yes**, I *really* want to do it! Otherwise I wouldn't have stored the credentials. How can I disable the <s>unnecessary</s> question/window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [safety feature](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.phishy-userpass-length)  of Mozilla to prevent phishing.

It used to be possible to turn it off by setting option `network.http.phishy-userpass-length` to `255` in `about:config`.

That option is not present any more in ff 42 by default.

According to this [support request](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1069670) it however is still possible to add it manually.

There is also an [SE post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12893) from May 2015 that mentions it.

Seems it's worth a try.